# A simple angular js program to render different views is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i am trying to write a simple Angular JS program but its not working
This is my html file:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html data-ng-app="myApp">
            <head>
                <title>SPA APP</title>
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div data-ng-view=""></div>
                <script src="my-module.js"></script>
                <script src="my-controller.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

This is my-module.js file

```
            var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
            myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                {
                    controller:'myController',
                    templateUrl:'view1.html'
                })
                .when('/view2',
                {
                    controller:'myController',
                    templateUrl:'view2.html'
                })
                .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
            });
```

And this is my-controller.js file

```
            myApp.controller('myController',function($scope){
                $scope.name="varun";
            });
```

Any help will be appericiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use Angular router, you need to include [`ngRoute` module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute), which is not shipped by default with  `angular.js` file.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

And then you need to declare dependency:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Having done this, you can use `$route` service in controllers, directives, etc. and `$routeProvider` in config section to set up routes.